# How to get the number of items in a combobox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

How can I get the number of items listed in a combobox?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try

```
var count = comboBox.Items.Count;
```

Answer (score 21):

You should reference `Count` of the [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx) property.

```
myComboBox.Items.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comboBox.Items.Count;
```

Doesn't work for me.

I use :

```
comboBox->count();
```

Comment: Thanks, I used Windows Forms, not WPF, I have made a note in my post for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Variable_name_JComboBox.getComponentCount()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this works and why it is the solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].