# How do I get the total number of index of a ComboBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application that has a combobox that varies in length depending on user input, is there I way that I can get the index length of a combobox?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the code behind?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the number of items in a combobox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768513/how-to-get-the-number-of-items-in-a-combobox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I got you right: Index length = number of items in the list?
Then you can just ask

```
var cb = new ComboBox();
var nrOfItems = cb.Items.Count;
```